# Google drive - drive.file scope is restricting my access to a shared file

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

In my application, I am using 'drive.file' scope for Google Drive access from the user. I share few files in google drive amongst the users that are created by my application. Now, once a file is shared with a user, the file is not accessible to that user because of "drive.file" scope saying '404 file not found' error. But when I replace the scope with full Drive access, the file is accessible. So is their a way I can use the restrictive scope as well as retrieve/access the shared files amongst the users of my application?

Answer (score 1):

Opening a file shared to user may need `auth/drive` full authorization, as stated in the related SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14630796/5995040), [Access to all files on a user's Google Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10331595/5995040)
, and [Google Drive api scope and file access (drive vs drive.files)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23696493/5995040)
, "to be precise the Drive API gives access to Files created by the app and files that the user has opened with the app from the Drive UI (through open-with)." You can try using `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly` if you just need to view file metadata and file content. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

When I last asked about it, there was not. You can see some discussion here:

https://plus.google.com/u/0/+JoeGibbsPolitz/posts/7xLaiAMUP8q?cfem=1

The conclusion of that thread, which I find pretty weird, is that *adding* the `drive.file` scope can actually *reduce* the authority of a request to the GDrive API.